Compute yaw-pitch-roll from accelerometer and gyroscope info
I'm writing a code to detect movements and I understand that I need to compensate the gravity effect of my sensors.
Checking online (here and here for example) I found that with an accelerometer I can only compute pitch and roll, while I could use the gyroscope to compute yaw and build the rotation matrix.
I defined my rotation matrix as
$R = 
 \begin{bmatrix}
cos(\text{yaw})cos(\text{pitch}) & cos(\text{yaw})sin(\text{pitch})sin(\text{roll})-sin(\text{yaw})cos(\text{roll}) & cos(\text{yaw})sin(\text{pitch})cos(\text{roll})+sin(\text{yaw})sin(\text{roll}) \\
sin(\text{yaw})cos(\text{pitch}) & sin(\text{yaw})sin(\text{pitch})sin(\text{roll})+cos(\text{yaw})cos(\text{roll}) & sin(\text{yaw})sin(\text{pitch})cos(\text{roll})-cos(\text{yaw})sin(\text{roll}) \\
-sin(\text{pitch}) & cos(\text{pitch})sin(\text{roll}) &  cos(\text{pitch})cos(\text{roll})\\
\end{bmatrix}
$
and using the first link, I invert this matrix and being $a$ my accelerometer vector $a = (a_x,a_y,a_z)^T$
I compute the compensation info as
$a_{comp} = R^{-1} a + (0,0,9.8)^T$
and in theory I get the acceleration information from my sensor without the gravity effect.
I compute
$\text{pitch} = atan^2(\frac{-a_x}{\sqrt{a_y^2+a_z^2}})$ and
$\text{roll}= atan^2(\frac{-a_y}{\sqrt{a_x^2+a_z^2}})$
But now I don't get it how to compute pitch. I found that I could integrate the z axis of the gyroscope in time: $\text{yaw} = g_z T$ where T is my sampling period. The problem here is that I loop the sensing, and so integrating $g_z$ in time gives me junk, from NaN to overflow.
Is there any other way to retrieve this info?
P.s: I'm using Arduino with an integrated IMU, so I extract acc and gyro info from here.

There is much here to say, but I will answer your question in detail.
So first of all, we need to define the rotation sequence. If you are working with an Arduino, you are probably talking about the aerospace sequence, where the final orientation is achieved by rotating from the initial orientation around the z-axis by the yaw angle, then around the new y-axis by the pitch angle, and then around the new x-axis by the roll angle.
I assume you are using the NED (North-East-Down) coordinate system as the reference (absolute) coordinate system. In this coordinate system, the global x-axis points north, the global y-axis points east and the global z-axis points down.
The second thing you should know is this: Without the magnetometer, you can not know the orientation of your local coordinate system (the IMU's coordinate system) with respect to the global coordinate system. The complete derivation of the yaw pitch and roll can be found here. If you had a magnetometer, to get the initial orientation, you would use formulas Eqn.13, Eqn.15 and Eqn.22 from the given document.
In any case, you lack one reference vector for obtaining yaw if you only use the accelerometer.
The third thing you should know is that the accelerometer and magnetometer can give you roll pitch and yaw when the device is static. If the device is rotating, the gyroscope can provide the angles if you integrate its values. For integration, you also need the initial angles which you obtain from the other two sensors at startup.
Finally, the integration of gyroscope data causes integration error accumulation. Especially in a static state. What you need to do is use a complementary filter to obtain good orientation. Use the MadgwickFilter.h library for this purpose. I also suggest you research the theory of complementary filters, quaternions, and the Madgwcik filter.
Bonus: Accelerometers often need calibration, as well as magnetometers. Don't forget to do that for reliable orientation estimation! Compensate for the magnetic declination in your code as well! Don't use Euler angles. Use quaternions to avoid Gimbal Lock!

Thank you for the detailed answer. Actually I'm using the Arduino IMU to detect small movements of a human body. At first I only used the z orientation of the accelerometer to detect movements but then I figured that I could lose the global movement, so I used the abs value of x, y z of my accelerometer and used a zero crossing approach to count the movement per minute. I didn't like the final result and searching in Google I found out I needed the gravity compensation. In my board I don't have a magnetometer (I think). I also saw that someone used GPS info to get yaw

Maybe I could connect my Arduino to the smartphone writing an app that shares the GPS info and use it to get yaw direction instead of computation? And maybe also using it to calibrate?

The GPS provides heading, that is true. If you know how to do that with your smart phone, that's great. I never did that in practice though. I worked with the NEO 6M GPS module.
